# range.sort.sortfields.add2 method simply give no error and no response

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

My first quetion here...
I´m trying to sort fields on descending. Here is the code:

```
With ContEstoque.Range("Cont_Estoque_tbl").Sort
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Cont_Estoque_tbl[[#All],[DATA DA CONTAGEM]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
End With
```

ContEstoque is the sheet name.
Cont_Estoque_tbl is a formated/named table in excel.

I´m simply getting no error and no response. Any guests?

[result after run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lM8NV.png)

Comment: Maybe it´s relevant... this code works if I run it in a new module.

Comment: @BigBen doesn´t work. Any other suggestion?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem would be `Range("Cont_Estoque_tbl[[#All],[DATA DA CONTAGEM]]")`, but just a guess. What happens when you use the macro recorder?

Comment: @BigBen The code was generated by macro recorder and adapted. This specific portion you mentioned wasn´t modifyied.

Comment: The code is running from other sheet in the same file called "Estoque" under Option Explicit / Sub Calcular_Estoque(). I didn´t set an specific module for it. The code sort a formatted table named "Cont_Estoque_tbl" that belongs to other sheet "ContEstoque".

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by isolating everything in defined variables. Not sure exactly what was the problem, but it works.

```
Dim srt_rng As Range
Dim tbl_lo As Object
        
        Set tbl_lo = ContEstoque.ListObjects("Cont_Estoque_tbl")
        Set srt_rng = ContEstoque.Range("Cont_Estoque_tbl[[#All],[DATA DA CONTAGEM]]")
        
        tbl_lo.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        tbl_lo.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=srt_rng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With tbl_lo.Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
```